# .NET Core Azure Function missing reference

Tags: nuget, .net-core, azure-functions

I've added a Nuget-package to my .NET Core "Azure Function"-project:

> Install-Package SharePointPnPCoreOnline -Version 2.22.1801

But I receive an error in my code:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
>   while executing function: StoreInDatabase --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions, Version=1.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e633289e95c321a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This assembly should be included from the Nuget Package, but it doesn't.
As I'm new to .NET Core and Azure Functions, does anyone know how to solve this one?

**Update**
I see the package has another version number than in the error-details.

[image: Version number incorrect]

But still no idea how to solve this... any ideas?

Comment: Is the referenced assembly compliant to .NET Standard?

Comment: I have no idea... how can I check this?

Comment: Looking at some of the package's dependencies on [its NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/), I would say that it's not compatible with .NET Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the nuget package with the wrong version number, I saw that previous versions are "hidden" in NuGet...

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions/

I solved this by installing the latest version of the package
So in my case, I just ran the command:

```
Install-Package SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions -Version 1.2.3
```